# How to integrate mRemote and putty/pageant?

Tags: ssh, putty, mremote

I would like to use mRemote to connect to a system that only has public-key authentication (instead of user/pass). I'm [led to believe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7700/how-to-enable-remote-login/7702#7702) it's possible to configure mRemote to use Putty/Pageant to do this, but I haven't found exactly how. Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

PuTTY is included as part of the mRemote package and is available to use straight away. To integrate pageant, download it from the putty [download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

What I have done is store it with PuTTY and then I created shortcut to it. I edited the shortcut properties and changed the Target to include my private key e.g.

`C:\Program Files\mRemote\pageant.exe iain.ppk`

I have she thortcut run from the startup group when I login so all I have to do is provide the pass phrase for it and I'm good to go.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your explanation. I have both PUTTY and Pageant install. Can you explain in smaller words? E.g., what does "store it with PUTTY" mean?

Comment: Put it in the same directory as putty.

Comment: He means open putty.exe in c:\Program Files\mRemote\putty.exe, then expand the SSH Category... and select "Auth". Upload the private key to the server you want to log into, configure the username you use to login, and save this Session (likely as the name of the computer you want to log into). Then open the mRemote client, select the linux box you want to connect to... and go to "Config". Choose the Session you saved in the previous step. Good luck.